# How to get a single solution by simultaneously solving three equations with three variables?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following three equations having three variables.

```
ClearAll;
Clear[R2, R3, R4, r2, r3, r4, L2, L3, L4, L5];
L2 = 1.0; L3 = 2.0; L4 = 3.0; L5 = 30.0;
Do[Do[Do[Print[
FindRoot[ 
 2 (1 + R4 L4) ( (1 + R4 L4)^0.5  (1 - 1/R2) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(
        1 + R2 L2))^0.5 (1/R2 - 1/R3) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(
        1 + R3 L3))^0.5 (1/R3 - 1/R4) + 1/R4  ) - L5 == 0
&& 2 (1 + 
  R4 L4) ( (1 + R4 L4)^1.5  (1 - 1/R2) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(
    1 + R2 L2))^1.5 (1/R2 - 1/R3) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(
    1 + R3 L3))^1.5 (1/R3 - 1/R4) + 1/R4  ) - 3 L5 == 0
&& 2 (1 + 
  R4 L4) ( (1 + R4 L4)^2.5  (1 - 1/R2) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(
    1 + R2 L2))^2.5 (1/R2 - 1/R3) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(
    1 + R3 L3))^2.5 (1/R3 - 1/R4) + 1/R4  ) - 5 L5 == 0
, {{R2, 1.0}, {R3, 1.0}, {R4, 1.0}}]], {r2, 0.879, 1.0, 0.1}], {r3, 
  0.9, 1.0, 0.1}], {r4, 0.9, 1.0, 0.1}]
```

The output:

```
    FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but could not find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but could not find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but could not find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}

{R2->0.898056,R3->3.10929,R4->1.13828}
```

As one can observe, there are multiple values of {R2, R3, R4} corresponding to the different values of r2,r3, and r4. Is it possible to get a single set of values for {R2, R3, R4}? If yes, then what is the best way to achieve it?

The journal paper that I'm following had a solution of {R2, R3, R4} = {0.9066, 2.1798, 1.2204}.

Thank you so much in advance. I'll appreciate your help.

It would be also helpful if you can provide a link to an answer to a similar kind of problem.

Comment: Check the solution: If the paper's solution is plugged into the LHS's of the equation, I get `{-18.1791, -71.7943, -133.655}`, which are not very close to zero. If the paper's solution is correct, there's a mistake in the system. Or vice versa.

Comment: Incorrect setup: `{{R2, 1.0}, {R3, 1.0}, {R4, 1.0}}` should be `{{R2, r2}, {R3, r3}, {R4, r4}}` to start search at the locations specified in the nested `Do`s.  Also see [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead of `Do`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use exact values when possible:

```
L2 = 1; L3 = 2; L4 = 3; L5 = 30;

eqns = {2 (1 + 
          R4 L4) ((1 + R4 L4)^0.5 (1 - 
             1/R2) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(1 + R2 L2))^0.5 (1/R2 - 
             1/R3) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(1 + R3 L3))^0.5 (1/R3 - 1/R4) + 
          1/R4) - L5 == 0, 
     2 (1 + 
          R4 L4) ((1 + R4 L4)^1.5 (1 - 
             1/R2) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(1 + R2 L2))^1.5 (1/R2 - 
             1/R3) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(1 + R3 L3))^1.5 (1/R3 - 1/R4) + 
          1/R4) - 3 L5 == 0, 
     2 (1 + 
          R4 L4) ((1 + R4 L4)^2.5 (1 - 
             1/R2) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(1 + R2 L2))^2.5 (1/R2 - 
             1/R3) + ((1 + R4 L4)/(1 + R3 L3))^2.5 (1/R3 - 1/R4) + 
          1/R4) - 5 L5 == 0} // Rationalize // Simplify;

sol = Sort /@ NSolve[eqns, {R2, R3, R4}, PositiveReals]

(* {{R2 -> 0.85298, R3 -> 8.49764, R4 -> 2.27966}, {R2 -> 0.893403, 
  R3 -> 2.66003, R4 -> 2.70195}, {R2 -> 0.893874, R3 -> 0.448215, 
  R4 -> 2.69833}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
(#[[1]] - #[[-1]] & /@ eqns) /. sol // Chop

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```